# How to permit running an application only within a predefined time

Tags: macos

I am looking for a way to forbid myself from running an RSS application I am spending too much time on during the day. What I want is to turn on the app when I wake up, read the news, and once I am done, to quit the app, and not be able to run this app until the next morning.

Comment: How are you typically launching the app? From Finder, the Dock, Spotlight, some other method?

Comment: This has been asked many times. And there are a few ways of doing it. But the question you may want to ask yourself is. If you cannot control yourself now. Then what is stopping you bypassing what ever someone suggests?

Comment: @bneely I use Dock or Spootlight.

Answer (score 2):

[SelfControl](http://selfcontrolapp.com) is free and lets you lock access to a url for a period of time... It would require you to switch to an online RSS reader like [Feedly](http://feedly.com) though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but shifting to a browser based RSS reader is not acceptable for me.

Comment: @dwightk This answer is not a requirement. It is an option..

Comment: This answer would require, not any answer